# When NOT to use Azure Virtual WAN?

Tags: networking, azure

I have been studying Azure Virtual WAN. The idea of a managed architecture hub and spoke networking architecture seems great.

One thing that the documentation does not address is when it would be appropriate not to use VWAN but instead to stick with the traditional peered hub and spoke architecture.

azure
virtual
wan

Answer (score 0):

I think virtual wan is overkill when you are not in multiple regions,or not use a multi region architecture.